# MySQL CASE to update one column from multiple columns + LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql-update, case, multiple-columns, sql-like

I was wondering if this is possible to update one column from values in different other columns... something like:

```
UPDATE table
    SET column1 = CASE column2,column3
        WHEN column2 == test AND column3 == 1 THEN 100
        WHEN (column2 LIKE %test1% OR column2 LIKE %test2%) AND column3 == 2 THEN 50
        ELSE 0
    END
```

Thanks for any answer!

EDIT : answer for others who might have the same problem:

```
UPDATE table
    SET column1 = CASE 
        WHEN column2 = test AND column3 = 1 THEN 100
        WHEN (column2 LIKE '%test1%' OR column2 LIKE '%test2%') AND column3 = 2 THEN 50
        ELSE 0
    END
```

Comment: Try removing column2, column3 after the CASE.

Comment: And make sure %test1% and %test2% are in quotes

Comment: it doesn't seem to work... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "column2, column3" after case and try following thing,

```
UPDATE table
    SET column1 = CASE WHEN column2 == test AND column3 == 1 THEN 100
        WHEN (column2 LIKE '%test1%' OR column2 LIKE '%test2%') AND column3 == 2 THEN 50
        ELSE 0
    END
```

following is the link to guide you more about CASE statement:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html